# Unable to locate and click checkbox ::before using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm trying to click a checkbox but it's keep clicking the link 'terms and conditions'. Although my xpath (mentioned below) work on a minimized window but it's failing to click the checkbox when the window is maximized because the href (image) appears in the second line next to checkbox. Looking for some suggestions on clicking the checkbox widget on maximized window. I need to get a focus on it.

Interestingly, when i hover over the ::before (css selector) only than the widget gets highlighted.

```
<div class="checkbox u-mar-bot-5">
  <div class="checkbox__container">
    <input class="checkbox__input" type="checkbox" id="basket-contact-terms" required data-parsley-multiple="basket-contact-terms" style>
<label class="checkbox__label checkbox__label--has-link checkbox__label--small" for="basket-contact-terms" style>
::before 
"I have read and agree to " <a class="text-link text-link--base text-link- small" href="/terms-conditions" target="_blank">Terms and Conditions</a>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

image: [Terms and Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qlqx.png)

I tried a few options that keep failing to check the box and instead the link 'terms and conditions' gets the click. I must be missing something basic.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='basket-contact-terms']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(@class,'checkbox__label checkbox__label--has-link checkbox__label--small')]")).click();
```

I did looked around and found someone suggested to use this (below) so i tried but didn't work:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'checkbox u-mar-bot-5')]"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elem).click().build().perform();
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `driver.findElement(By.id("basket-contact-terms")).click();`

Comment: Thanks @Andersson, i have tried what you suggested as well as "//input[@id='basket-contact-terms']" and for both i get 'org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible' exception. Both are valid selectors patterns but it's not the one i need when i do inspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you tried the ID of the `INPUT` and it threw an error that it wasn't visible, I would first try a wait to see if it will become visible. (I'm assuming it won't but it's worth a try first).

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("basket-contact-terms"))).click();
```

If that doesn't work, I would next try to click a different position on the element. By default, Selenium clicks on the center of the element. In your case, I think this is what's causing the issue. You can use `Actions` to click the upper left (1,1) of the element.

```
WebElement label = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='basket-contact-terms']"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(label, 1, 1).click().perform();
```

Comment: Excellent @JeffC! I used the upper left (1,1) suggestions and it worked perfectly. Yes, my problem was based on the window size and how the element would appear and in my case the anchor text was at it's centre. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

`WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.id("basket-contact-terms"))`

Comment: Thanks @Govind. Andersson suggested above the same. I have tried this but no luck.